# Firebase Error: com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase

my app does not access firebase data in the release version, but in the debug version it works normally.

Firebase error: com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Your current question is too broad, you need to at lease tell us what you have tried so far and where exactly you're stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u are using obfuscation in the release build, u should keep your data-classes not obfuscated, otherwise it will not match.
Try:

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep

@Keep
class MyClass {
}
```

Comment: to each your data class (the class of the object your are trying to retrieve from FB)

Comment: Thank you, it works.